# Convert a long string to ASCII in SQL

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

An ID field in my data is case-sensitive. I'm using Power BI to analyze that data and it's not case-sensitive. So I want to write a SQL syntax that would convert the IDs to ASCII. the IDs have 14 characters made up of numbers, and upper&lower case letters. If there is a way to do this in Power BI, that works too.

This is the long and dumb way I have: CONCAT(SUBTRING(ASCII(ID,1,1)),SUBTRING(ASCII(ID,2,1))......SUBTRING(ASCII(ID,14,1)))

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you. A `uniqueidentifier` is made up of the characters 0-9, a-f and -, so it's already ASCII. A `uniqueidentifier` is also not case sensitive.

Comment: I'm confused: a `uniqueidentifier` is just a 16-byte array, it doesn't have upper or lowercase any more than 10 or 42 does

Comment: Sorry, my bad for calling it a unique identifier. Updated it to ID field

Answer (score 0):

Converting all the characters in your ID to the ASCII number seems pretty much work for something that can be solved much easier.  Just create a new table in your database with an identity column (the surrogate key) and your ID.  Then insert all distinct values of your ID in this table.  When importing tables into Power BI you just JOIN this new table and in Power BI you do your analysis on the new SK column instead of the uid.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have read access to the database.

Comment: A handful of them.. using this ID field to set up the relationships in Power BI

Comment: You could use a ##temp table then you only need read access, but I guess that will make your refreshes in Power BI very painful.

Comment: How about adding a BINARY CHECKSUM to the id, like SELECT CONCAT(ID,'_',BINARY_CHECKSUM(ID) ) AS NEW_ID